# Positioning image on a custom view, clarification needed

Tags: uiview, size, measurement

I have a view sized `320 x 376`

On top of this view, i'd like to place a UIImageView leaving 4 (not sure what is the unit of measurements here) points to each size. This (i hope) will create a frame around the image.

So, from the stand point of the view,

- Starting x,y coordinates will be `4 x 4.`
- Calculating the width of the top view, i `320 - 4 - 4 = 312`
- Calculating the height of the top view, i `376 - 4 - 4 = 368`

When said measurements are in place, however i get

[image]

[image]

**Why am i not seeing a 4 points buffer towards the bottom?**

Comment: hmm..how can i repro this problem?  when i create a new view of fixed size and put in a subview of a slightly smaller size, it looks fine for me.  any more details on how this happened?

Comment: Are you sure your back view (or the view this back view is in) is not shorter than 368 (in height)? Because it should definitely work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with your params, it's ok for me :

[image]

The only reason that I found to explain why this happens is because the view that is behind the 2 others (border view + image view) is shorter than 376, so it hides the bottom of your views :

(here, it's the green one)

OK
[image]

Too short
[image]